# Laravel - Call to a member function file() on null { "userId": 1, "exception": {

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-9

I'm trying to upload files from my app but for some reasons I get " Call to a member function file() on null ". I have created the storage:link.

I am using craftable to make a crud.

This is one of my view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-create" method="post"             
      @submit.prevent="onSubmit" :action="action" novalidate  
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
                <div class="card-header">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{ trans('admin.vado.actions.create') }}
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @include('admin.vado.components.form-elements')
                </div>
                                
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="submiting">
                        <i class="fa" :class="submiting ? 'fa-spinner' : 'fa-download'"></i>
                        {{ trans('brackets/admin-ui::admin.btn.save') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
```

This is another part of my view:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" id="foto_ampliacion" name="foto_ampliacion" placeholder="{{ trans('admin.vado.columns.foto_ampliacion') }}">
```

My controller

```
    public function store(StoreVado $request)
    {       
        
        // Sanitize input
        $sanitized = $request->getSanitized();
        

        $file = $request->file('foto_ampliacion');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        
    // Almacena el archivo
    $path = $file->storeAs('images', $fileName, 'public');
    $sanitized["foto_ampliacion"] = '/storage/' . $path;

    // Almacena el Vado
    $vado = Vado::create($sanitized);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return ['redirect' => url('admin/vados'), 'message' => trans('brackets/admin-ui::admin.operation.succeeded')];
        }

        return redirect('admin/vados');
    }
```

I get " Call to a member function file() on null ".

Comment: Why should `$request['inputImage']` exist? As far as I can see, you don't have a form field with that name `inputImage` anywhere.

Comment: Have you dumped/ checked what you are receiving in $request in the first place?

Comment: I have changed that, but the error persists. I have updated it in the first comment. I checked $request, but recive null on $request in foto_apliacion

Comment: Have you inspected the request parameter in your browser dev tools yet, do those look okay?

Comment: Yes, that parameter arrive to the controller as null

Comment: I did not ask you to verify what arrives, but what is send in the first place.

Comment: I just checked that, and what it sends is "". There may be some error in the input?

Comment: Either that (`placeholder` for example makes no sense for a file input to begin with, although that should hardly be able to cause such an error), or it is somehow not actually a part of your form element.

Comment: But all the fields load their content except the file type, I don't know why

Comment: Is this a normal form submission, or does any JavaScriot interfere (reading the form field values, and then creating & making the request itself in the background)? I don't know what the meaning of `@submit.prevent="onSubmit"` is, but that sounds JS-related.